# How do I assign values to text in excel and then add them

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example... I want to assign the value 1 to A, 2 to B and 3 to C and then be able to add a row containing a combination of A, B and C's?

A   B   B   C   B   C   A = 14

Need some help... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use COUNTIF like this

`=SUM(COUNTIF(A1:G1,{"A","B","C"})*{1,2,3})`

You can vary {1,2,3} as required

Answer (score 2):

To add values in `A1:G1`, use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(A1:G1,{"A","B","C"},0))
```

This generates an array of 7 numbers corresponding to the position in the array `{"A","B","C"}` that matches each letter and then sums the array of numbers.

For example, if `A1:G1` hold `A B B C B C A`, this formula will generate the array `{1,2,2,3,2,3,1}` and then sum its contents.