# Excel - Assign a value to a character and remove cells from range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have row of cells containing a single letter each. Each letter as a numerical value and I need to add them all together. I'm using the following formula (as suggested by [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/702254/how-do-i-assign-values-to-text-in-excel-and-then-add-them)):

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(E2:DS2,{"A*","A","B","C"})*{4,3,2,1})
```

If the row contains the cells B C B A it should return 8 but at the moment it returns 12.

I'm also interested in excluding certain cells from the range. For example, CD, CJ, CV and DH. I know doing the following will work but surely there must be a more efficient way of doing it.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(E2:DS2,{"A*","A","B","C"})*{4,3,2,1})-SUM(COUNTIF(CD,{"A*","A","B","C"})*{4,3,2,1})-SUM(COUNTIF(CJ,{"A*","A","B","C"})*{4,3,2,1})-SUM(COUNTIF(DH,{"A*","A","B","C"})*{4,3,2,1})-SUM(COUNTIF(CV,{"A*","A","B","C"})*{4,3,2,1})
```

Need some help... Thanks!

Comment: The problem with your first formula is the "A*". I'm not sure why you added that (it isn't in the post you linked to). Both "A*" and "A" will match the "A" in row 2, adding 4 to your expected result of 8.

Comment: @Blackwood thanks for pointing that out. Realized * in Excel is a wildcard so needs to be taken as a literal with a ~.